# SimpleAudioEngine: No Music After Phone Sleeps

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, audio, simpleaudioengine

I just want to ask if it is possible to stop music from playing when the device sleeps?

I am using `SimpleAudioEngine` to play music. A user is claiming that the music stops from playing when his phone slept, turning on and off the sound from settings (there's an on/off feature for it) didn't fix the problem.

I tried to reproduce the bug but I can't reproduce it. Is there anyone who experience this kind of problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in appDelegate:----

```
void AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground()
{
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->resume();
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->startAnimation();

    // if you use SimpleAudioEngine, it must resume here
     SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->resumeBackgroundMusic();
}
```